# Variation of Einstein-Hilbert action in $D = 2$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, action, topological-field-theory

I know that Einstein tensor is null in 2 dimensions (1 time and 1 spatial coordinate). But, from the action 
$$
\int d^2x \sqrt{-g} R
$$
how can I prove that this action is  pure divergence, i.e. it is a topological invariant?

Comment: It is not a fun prospect, since it involves the Lorentzian version of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem and Lorentzian polygons : https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.mmj/1029002964

It is much simpler to show that the Einstein tensor is identically $0$ for all metrics.